# Java Serialization / Deserialization of an ArrayList works only on first program execution

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization, deserialization

I try to serialize and deserialize an ArrayList with some Objects. The first time I run the program, everything works, but the next times it doesn't work:

```
public class Test {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "Objects.ser";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<CustomObject> customObjects = getCustomObjects();
        System.out.println("CustomObjects count: "+customObjects.size());
        System.out.println("Adding 5 CustomObjects");
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
            obj.setIntValue(rand.nextInt());
            customObjects.add(obj);
        }
        System.out.println("CustomObjects count: "+customObjects.size());
        System.out.println("Save and load CustomObjects");
        saveCustomObjects(customObjects);
        customObjects = getCustomObjects();
        System.out.println("CustomObjects count: "+customObjects.size());
    }

    public static ArrayList<CustomObject> getCustomObjects(){
        try (
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FILE_NAME);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        ){
            return (ArrayList<CustomObject>) ois.readObject();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

    }

    public static void saveCustomObjects(ArrayList<CustomObject> strategies) {
        try(
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME, true);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        ){
            oos.writeObject(strategies);
            //tried also with oos.flush();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class CustomObject implements Serializable{

    static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

    private int intValue=0;
    private EnumTypes enumType=EnumTypes.ENUM_TYPE_ONE;

    public enum EnumTypes{
        ENUM_TYPE_ONE, ENUM_TYPE_TWO
    }

    public int getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public void setIntValue(int intValue) {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public EnumTypes getEnumTypes() {
        return enumType;
    }

    public void setEnumTypes(EnumTypes enumTypes) {
        this.enumType = enumTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.intValue;
        hash = 97 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.enumType);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CustomObject other = (CustomObject) obj;
        if (this.intValue != other.intValue) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.enumType != other.enumType) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomObject{" + "intValue=" + intValue + ", enumTypes=" + enumType + '}';
    }
}
```

The output of the first run of the app shows everything like expected:

```
CustomObjects count: 0
Adding 5 CustomObjects
CustomObjects count: 5
Save and load CustomObjects
CustomObjects count: 5
```

But after the next runs, the output looks always like the file with the objects in the serialized ArrayList could not be overwritten:

```
CustomObjects count: 5
Adding 5 CustomObjects
CustomObjects count: 10
Save and load CustomObjects
CustomObjects count: 5
```

I tested in netbeans and console on mac. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Don't append to the file, if you want to overwrite the file.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly that, nothing is overwritten, since you explicitely chose to append rather than overwrite when writing to the file:

```
new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME, true);
```

So the first run reads nothing, and appends a list of 5 elements to the file. The second run reads the unique list and appends another list of 10  elements to the file. The third run reads the first list of in the file, and appends yet another list of 10 elements, etc.

Remove the second argument, or set it to false.

Comment: Thank you very much